How to print pdf file using QPrinter?
I can't print my pdf file using QPrinter, I figured it needs to be set to html to print it and now I'm getting this error on terminal:

QPrintDialog: Cannot be used on non-native printers.

And does setting it to html like this change what my pdf file look like?.
def print_pdf(self, pdffile):
    printer = QPrinter()
    printer.setOutputFileName(pdffile)  
    printer.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize.PageSizeId.A6))  

    # Create a QTextDocument to hold the contents of the PDF file
    document = QTextDocument()
    document.setHtml("<html><body><img src='file://" + pdffile + "'/></body></html>")  # Load PDF content

    # a print dialog
    print_dialog = QPrintDialog(printer, self)
    
  
    if print_dialog.exec() == QPrintDialog.DialogCode.Accepted:
        # Print the document
        document.print(printer)


Sorry but that code doesn't make a lot of sense: 1. QTextDocument cannot show PDF content; 2. Even if it were able to do it, PDF is not an image and cannot therefore use the <img> tag; 3. you're trying to print on a pdf file that you're also attempting to display inside the very document you're printing, which makes absolutely no sense at all. It's also unclear what you actually want to do: do you already have a PDF file that you want to print on a physical printer?

yes i already have the pdf file. No i dont want to display it, just want to print it on a physical printer

any way i could print the pdf file using qprinter? I need qprinter specifically for the qprintdialog the user needs to choose other available printers

You could use the QPdfDocument class to render each page to a QImage and finally print those images to the QPrinter. In any case, you shall not call setOutputFileName(), since you obviously do not need to print to an output file.

Or you can dodge this procedure entirely and you can rely on a web browser for that task. Nowadays, everyone has a browser installed, and if you're targeting windows, Edge is there to ensure it.

yes that would be way easier, but the client seems to want it to remain on the app not relying on the browser

Does this answer your question? How to print pdf file in Qt

no im using python

For Qt related stuff, there is not a great difference between C++ and python, I created a new answer under that question to include the QPdfDocument solution (which wasn't available a that time) described by musicamente in his comment.
